# creating excel sheet using php

Tags: php, excel, compiler-errors, echo

im facing a problem at this particular line..

```
echo pack("ssssss", 0×809, 0×8, 0×0, 0×10, 0×0, 0×0);
```

the error that's coming is..

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\amc\excel.php on line 20
```

im not understanding why this is happening cause its the right syntax for echoing the pack function (i referred http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_pack.asp)

could someone help me out here..
PS: i got same error in next few lines where i used same piece of code of echoing pack with exactly same error when i tried commenting this line 20.

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code, please? The error might be being generated on an earlier line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0×809` this is not hex number,  it contains unicode character `×`. You should use simple `x` in hex notation.

Or just use good IDE that will mark this error for you.

Comment: Those scary dead eyes of yours are pretty sharp!

Answer (score 2):

The character you have it is `&times` and it displays this way: `×`! But we need to use plain `x` (the character, which comes after w, and before y).

So replace:

```
echo pack("ssssss", 0×809, 0×8, 0×0, 0×10, 0×0, 0×0);
```

With:

```
echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
```

And it should work! `:)`